# CMake: download precompiled binaries

Tags: c++, cmake, continuous-integration

I am trying to download precompiled binaries from a webserver within cmake. So is there something similar like `ExternalProject_Add` but without the actual build step?

The downloaded file is a tar.gz and would need to be extracted. It contains `/bin` `/include` and `/lib` and especially also `/lib/cmake` which should be found by the calling CMake project.

If I `ExternalProject_Add` results in an error that the build folder does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.

The minium example is something like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(Foo)
if (TARGET Bar)
    message(STATUS "Foo and Bar are unified - how beautiful is that")
else()
    include (ExternalProject)
    ExternalProject_Add ( Bar  # <------ This doesn't work
        URL "http://THE-INTERNET"
    )
endif()
find_package(Bar REQUIRED)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Bar::Bar)
```

---

Ok, I figured out two things:

1. The command `CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""` can be provided to ExternalProject to not build anything.
2. The `find_package()` will never work like this. The ExternalProject is executed during compile time, while the find_package needs to find the target at configure time.

In the meantime I found this: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html - this might help to get targets ready during configure time and not just during compile time. However it is only supported from CMake 3.11 on :(

Comment: And what is the problem you have? What have you tried? Do you have a [mcve] of your attempt to show us? What problems do you have with that? Please take some time to refresh [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Ok, I updated the question

Comment: What CMake version are you using? CMake makes it very easy to update versions.

Comment: I installed cmake via apt install on Ubuntu 18.04. The latest version I get is 3.10.

Comment: You could probably do this with [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) to call commands to download and extract the contents. If you want to be more cross-platform, the file download can be done with [`file(DOWNLOAD)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#download). There's also `file(ARCHIVE_EXTRACT)`, but that's new in CMake 3.18.